# Bootstrap accordion icons not working on collapsed states

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, icons, accordion, glyphicons

I am working on a accordion in Bootstrap V 3.37. I have icons on the accordion which change with open and closed states. When I the state set to `collapse in`it works fine. But when I have the accordion with none of them accordions `collapsed in` the icons are not working properly.

The icons should be working as:

1. Arrow facing down on closed state
2. Arrow facing up on open state

My code is as follows so far:

**HTML Structure**

```
<!-- Panel list accordion -->
<div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel-heading-one panel-main-heading-one">
         <h4 class="panel-title panel-main-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
               <img src="../images/image.svg" class="panel-icon">
               <p>Title here</p>
            </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body panel-bodymain-one">
            <p>Text body here</p>
         </div>
      </div>
            <div class="panel-heading-one panel-main-heading-one">
         <h4 class="panel-title panel-main-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
               <img src="../images/image.svg" class="panel-icon">
               <p>Title here</p>
            </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body panel-bodymain-one">
            <p>Title body here</p>
         </div>
      </div>
            <div class="panel-heading-one panel-main-heading-one">
         <h4 class="panel-title panel-main-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
               <img src="../images/image.svg" class="panel-icon">
               <p>Title here</p>
            </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body panel-bodymain-one">
            <p>Text body here</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- End panel list accordion -->
```

**CSS**

```
.panel-heading-one .accordion-toggle:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e113"; 
    float: right;        
    color: #ffffff;         
    height: 24px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.panel-heading-one .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e114";
}
```

Screenshots attached also.

Closed state - still point up:

[image]

Open state is fine as it points up:

[image]

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your css to:

```
.panel-heading-one .accordion-toggle:after{
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e114"; 
    float: right;        
    color: #ffffff;         
    height: 24px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.panel-heading-one .accordion-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
        /* symbol for "opening" panels */
        content: "\e113";
    }

.panel-heading-one .accordion-toggle[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e114";
}
```

And it will work perfectly.

> Extra: In your accordion you have used same `href='#collapseThree'`
>   for last and second last item. When you will click on last element, it
>   will open second last item. So change your `href` in last element.

Comment: When I apply your suggestion the first time I load the page the accordions that are 'collapsed in' the first time I click on that one the icon does not change how it should, but after it does, any ideas?

Comment: Actually after checking now the collapsed in accordions have the arrow pointing down not up how the open state should be?

Comment: When the accrodion is in collapsed state, the arrow should be pointing down as it signifies that something is going to open downwards. When the accordion is open, the arrow must point upwards as it tells that accrodion will close upwards.